# how do i filter this json after deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, filter, deserialization

```
responsestring = 

 "{\"resultList\": 
      [{\"modelId\":11,\"modelName\":\"indvsves12\",\"modelLang\":\"en-US\",\"modelVersion\":6,\"scoreMap\":{\"individual\":0.5,\"vessel\":0.5},\"bestCategory\":\"vessel\"}]}"
```

how do i filter this json after deserialization?
my deserialization code is

```
responsestring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
                        ClassifierResponse Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassifierResponse>(responsestring);
```

Comment: What filter do you need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you want the object or a specific property value. So providing both example.

```
string responsestring ="{\"resultList\": [{\"modelId\":11,\"modelName\":\"indvsves12\",\"modelLang\":\"en - US\",\"modelVersion\":6,\"scoreMap\":{\"individual\":0.5,\"vessel\":0.5},\"bestCategory\":\"vessel\"}]}";

//responsestring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
ClassifierResponse Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassifierResponse>(responsestring);

ResultList filObject = Response.Resultlist.Find(x => x.ModelId == 11);
string modelName = Response.Resultlist.Find(x => x.ModelId == 11).ModelName;
```

Comment: Find is not a good approach for large data

Answer (score 0):

**Please specify what filters you need, otherwise, its a wide open question.**

Assuming you are looking for filter on the ResultList, since that's the only viable option I can see. Once deserialized, you can use it like any other LINQ objects. For example (code not tested):

```
var x = Response.ResultList.Where(d => d.ModelName == "indvsves12").ToList();
```

Comment: i want filter and take this every values inside the response and map it to response class properties . and then comapre the scores of individual and vessel.@Guru Stron

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **LINQ** Query also

```
var x = from x in Response.ResultList where x.ModelName == "indvsves12" select x.ModelName ;
```

Use `foreach` to extract multiple records.

**EDIT**:

as discussion in commnent you need to get the records from `scoremap`
and you are getting error in deserialization

First update your class from

```
 public class Scoremap
{
    public double Individual { get; set; }
    public double Vessel { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
public class Scoremap
{
    public double Individual { get; set; }
    public double Vessel { get; set; }
    public string bestCategory { get; set; }
}
```

It will resolve error deserialization

then simply you can use

```
var x = from x in Response.ResultList where x.ModelName == "indvsves12" select x;
    foreach(var items in x)
    {
      string val1 = item.scoreMap.individual;
      string val2 = item.scoreMap.vessel;
      string val3 = item.scoreMap.bestCategory;
    }
```

Comment: I want only to access the scores of indivdual and vessel to compare them in if condition and use it@Ahmed

Comment: i can able to access the values inside the response by Response.ResultList.modelID when i change the class to public  Resultlist resultList {get;set;}. But when i do that im getting error in deserialization part as  Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Please help me with code of getting the values of scores of indivdual and vessel and best category from response @Ahmed@Guru Stron @r2018

Comment: you want to extract the value of inner object `Scoremap` right ?

Comment: update your `scoremap` class and add property for `bestCategory` because when json object try to map it with you dynamic class it didnot find the property for mapping `bestCategory` thats why it shows error add this property `public string bestCategory{ get; set; }` for resolving your solution

Comment: I have updated answer please upvote if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own i can able to access the response values like this :Response.ResultList[0].Scoremap.Indivdual.